# nginx: subdomains, map to 2nd host with multiple ports

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I have been looking for an nginx reverse proxy config that can:

- receive incoming traffic from my router on port 80, from mydomain.com;
- from subdomains, say sd01, sd02, sd03.
- i.e. sd01.mydomain.com - then must go via the nginx reverse proxy (host1), and point the request to host2 (all RPi's) behind my router, and be routed to a different port on this host2.

On host2 (ip address say 192.168.1.33), I have docker running several instances of node-red, each container pointing to a different port on host2:

 `- sd01.mydomain.com to point to 192.168.1.33:1101
 - sd02.mydomain.com to point to 192.168.1.33:1102
 - sd03.mydomain.com to point to 192.168.1.33:1103`

I have seen so many options of doing this on the web, from using 
`map $subdomain $subdomain_port {`
to others, but I cannot get it working. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

And yes, I have added the wildcard * directive on godaddy for the sub domains to point to the fixed ip of my router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the upstream directive in association with a proxy_pass in the location directive for this.

ie.

```
upstream sd01 {
    server 192.168.1.33:1101;
}

upstream sd02 {
    server 192.168.1.33:1102;
}

upstream sd03 {
    server 192.168.1.33:1103;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www;
    server_name sd01.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://sd01/;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www;
    server_name sd02.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://sd02/;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www;
    server_name sd03.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://sd03/;
    }
}
```

Note that if you are using sockets you will need to upgrade the connection for that path:

```
location /socket/ {
   proxy_pass http://socketserverupstream;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```

This is a similar configuration that I use for all of my servers. You can however refer to the [NGINX documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html).

Comment: Thank you for answering RyanP, I am traveling for 2 weeks to CA and SanFran, will test afterwards, and let you know, thanks again.

Comment: Jean, how did you get on? If you need more help, feel free to drop a comment.

Comment: Hello Ryan, apologies for not trying yet, I am on a 2 weeks trip to Toronto and San Ramon, will try next week. Thank you for the offer & assistance, I really want to get this working! (I am from South Africa - so a tough 2 weeks travel schedule....)

Answer (score 2):

In your nginx configuration file(nginx.conf) do these changes:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name  sd01;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1101;
    }
}

server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name  sd02;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1102;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this might answer the question, please consider adding some explanation.